# My GitHub profile is not visible to others

Tags: github

My GitHub username is **raj-pragadeesh**

My GitHub profile https://github.com/raj-pragadeesh is not visible to others. My public projects are also not visible. My PRs are not visible to the users in the same project. If my username is searched, other users cannot find my profile.

I have raised a discussion in the GitHub community forum but it is not responsive

Link to the discussion: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/87308

The weird part is the discussion that I posted is also not visible to others.

What is the solution for this?

[image: Discussion screenshot]

[image: Profile not found]

[image: My Profile]

[image: Public setting]

Comment: Some problem with your account, you need to contact github support. Someone with a similar problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/github/comments/174qzv9/was_my_github_account_shadowbanned/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to **Github's abuse-detecting systems** highlighting accounts that need to be manually reviewed.

It can only be solved by contacting GitHub support. Raising a question in the community forum will not work. You have to raise it as a bug report or any other issue. Only by then you will get a response from the GitHub support team and your account will be fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your profile visibility setting https://github.com/settings/profile

Under > Contributions & activity

Is it unchecked? [ ] Make profile private and hide activity

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the profile visibility setting. And even if that is checked, only your contributions and activity will not be visible, not your account itself. Other persons should be able to find me with my username. That visibility setting should not disturb that.